# MVC - Yii2 reorganize my code structure from backend to frontend

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, reorganize

in my company i have one app with Yii2 Framework (MVC) divided between frontend and backend, some people use frontend and others use backend. Now i need (by the reason of integrity and ease of access of users) integrate all in frontend (leave backend only for the admnistrators).

For example i have one module like a "Call Center" where only 
the telephonists save the calls in backend.
So in frontend (with diferent layout, permissions, fields, filters etc..) the others users see, edit and work yours calls.
Now i need pass the module "call center" from backend (where only telephonists have access) to frontend.

What the best way organize my code? 
I thought to assing one "suffix" for de code comming from backend and organize my code like this:

**Controllers**

```
 CallCenterController.php
 CallCenterAdmin.php
```

**Views**

```
call-center
   index.php
   view.php

call-center-admin
   index.php
   view.php
   form.php
```

Is this correct? 
Or thes best solution is one controller and one folder with views for module "call-center" unique?
My objetive is change easyly permissions, layout, visible fields, filters etc..

Comment: what are you using for permissions ? `AccessControl` or RBAC? and if you are looking to move the controllers and views to the frontend, all you need to do is to change the namespaces for the controllers to `frontend\controllers` from `backend\controllers` and if you have the `models` folder in backend which you need to move to the `frontend\models` or `common\models`  you need to do the same for the models too and also change the `use` statements for those models used any where

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I use AccessControl and RBAC both. I see some problems, 1º already have the view folder with name "call-center" both in frontend and backend (for this purpose i suggested add the suffix), 2º i need maintain the module call-center in backend (for administrators access), not only move to frontend. btw i try change the namespace from `backend\controllers` to `frontend\controllers` and i receiv the error message  "Not Found (#404)"

Comment: Just create a new module with suggested name and be done with that. Also take time to correct all namespaces and use statements.

Comment: @Serghei Leonenco in your suggestion my app would be: `frontend\controllers`  and views (with all the code I already have in the frontend) and `frontend\modules\management` (with all code comming from backend, controllers and views) right?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: @Serghei Leonenco and what your opinion about the problems that user exru said?

Comment: User @exru proposed different architect structure, which gives you more advanced configuration features, by me you can use both methods. Also configuring RBAC in module structure can be implemented same way like you doing right now.

Comment: Also i do not agree with you @exru, about writing any special statements. The access is controlled same way like he has right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is your answer. You can create structure of your project on application level, not module level, with splited authorization, configs & web/index.php for example:

```
site:
--common
--console
--call-center:
---web:
----index.php
---views
---etc
--call-center-admin:
---web:
----index.php
---views:
---etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the  @Serghei Leonenco suggestion of creating one module inside the frontend would not make the code more organized?

Comment: He'll have a significant problems in this case. It's a workaround instead of "recommended refactoring".
By the way he have to write special RBAC rules using something like: Yii::$app->id == 'frontend'; //it's no good idea

Comment: yes you are correct. I was trying to avoid my code like this: `CallCenterController.php; CallCenterAdminController.php; OtherController.php; OtherControllerAdmin.php`. It's clear for you?

Comment: @Moutinho i gues the best way is making common->modules->controllers with combined(hybrid) rules for RBAC. In this case you will be reuse necessary logic of "actions" in every APPLICATION(frontend, backend, admin, call-center meaning) with adding\deleting some RBAC rules.